# bash equivalent of zsh's '=' command path expansion?

Tags: bash, zsh

zsh has a nice simple '=' expansion feature for commands:

```
$ zsh
% echo =sed
/usr/bin/sed
% file =bugzilla
/usr/bin/bugzilla: Python script, ASCII text executable
%
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion

Is there some convenient equivalent for bash?

The closest I can see is `type -tP <pgm>`, but still bit of a mouthful.

Comment: I don't think bash has a shortcut for this.

Comment: Right @Barmar, but maybe someone has some trick or way to do something similar :)

Comment: not knowing zsh, I don't know what you are expecting = to do. Either add a tag for zsh to bring in those experts, or explain more? Hope you don't mind, I added the tag.

Comment: `file "$(which <command>)"`? But it won’t work with builtins, e.g. `cd`.

Comment: `type -p` instead of `type -tP`, and you could `alias t='type -p'` but you still have `file "$(t cd)"`

Comment: @Biffen `cd` is a bad example, because often there *is* something like `/usr/bin/cd` installed (for reasons I can never remember). :)

Comment: @chepner Yep I changed the example :)
Actually dunno what `/usr/bin/cd` is used for...

But zsh's `=` expansion ignores builtin shell commands.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities.. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

bash doesn't offer any expansion like zsh, but it *does* have utils that give you info about the command:

[command -v](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/1p/command.htm) is a shell builtin that will tell you how your shell will invoke the command passed as an argument:

```
user@pc:~$  command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Using `-V` instead (upper case) will write a string to standard output indicating how the argument would be interpreted by the shell, in the current shell execution environment

```
user@pc:~$  command -V ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

[which](https://ss64.com/bash/which.html) steps through the `$PATH` environment variable and checks for the existence of a file and gives you the results found:

```
user@pc:~$ which ls
/bin/ls
user@pc:~$
```

[whereis](https://ss64.com/bash/whereis.html) will search `$PATH`, man pages and source files for an application file:

```
user@pc:~$ whereis ls
ls: 
/bin/ls 
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
user@pc:~$
```